# How to create a leap year generator in python 3

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to create a leap year generator with start, stop, and step that will calculate the number of leap years, sum of leap years, number of leap years divisible by 3, and the sum of leap years divisible by 3. I tried writing this code, but I don't think my answers are right because I keep getting the wrong number of years within the designated range.

```
def leap(start,stop,step=1):
    import calendar
    l=[]
    
    for i in range(start, stop+1,step):
        if i % 4 == 0:
            if i % 100 ==0:
                if i % 400 ==0:
                    l.append(i)
                else:
                    l.append(i)
    return l

l = leap(1901,2000,1)

print("number of leap years:",len(l))
print("sum of leap years:",sum(l))

c=0
s=0

for i in l:
    if i%3==0:
        c=c+1
        s=s+i  
print("leap years divisible by 3:",c)
print("sum of divisible leap years:",s)
```

I don't think Python is treating the `l = leap(1901,2000,1)` part as a range. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing `l.append(i)` on both branches of an `if` statement.

Comment: Your code says years divisble by 100 are leap years (and no other). Pick a few year numbers and in a mental experiment see which code gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `calendar` then use `.isleap()`?

```
def leap(start,stop,step=1):
    import calendar
    return [i for i in range(start,stop+1,step) if calendar.isleap(i)]

l = leap(1901,2000,1)
```

And if you want to use corrected condition:

```
def leap(start,stop,step=1):
    return [i for i in range(start,stop+1,step) if i % 4 == 0 and (i % 100 != 0 or i % 400 == 0)]

l = leap(1901,2000,1)
```

Comment: That worked! However, i'm not quite sure why this worked rather than using the conditional statements. Could you explain it to me if you can?

Comment: Modulus by 100 NEQ 0 or 400 EQ 0 should be OR because it should not be True both and AND should be with Modulus of 4 EQ 0, you were chaining three with AND